# Does PEP-8 mandate imports or global variables first?

Tags: python, pep8

May I know in a Python environment, which is compliant with [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)?

Imports before global variables:

```
import some_library
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = "something"
```

Or global variables before imports:

```
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = "something"
import some_library
```

Comment: The best practice is to not use a global variable.

Comment: I guess by "global variable" they mean a "constant".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says about imports:

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
> comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

so this

```
import some_library
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = "something"
```

is PEP-8 compliant, and this

```
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = "something"
import some_library
```

is not.

Answer (score -3):

The **standard** is for the imports to come before the global variables. There are several advantages to this:

1. If you import a file with a global of the same name, then the variable defined in the import will take priority.
2. If you import a file with another global, you won't have to write it here.
3. You can import a file of globals and isolate that complexity.

As mentioned in some other comments, using globals is not really the best practice in Python. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).

Comment: That last comment needs to be explained. Sounds a bit nonsensical as it stands.

Comment: Yeah I just needed to find the clearest source

Comment: Just saying what you mean clearly is fine.